# ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'container_name' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: docker-compose

When I ran: docker-compose up -d, I got error saying

"ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'container_name' must be a mapping not a string."

This is my yml file:

```
version'3' services:
    web:
    container_name: nginx1
    ports:
             - "8080:80"
    image: nginx
```

~

Comment: I see there have been a couple of edits to the question.  @natukita, can you please make sure the question contains the _exact_ YAML you have, with the correct indentation and punctuation?  The error message suggests a syntactic or formatting error.

Answer (score 0):

Version is property, also whitespaces has meaning in yaml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: nginx1
...
```